Does this projection make sense?

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we let $\pi_i(x)$ be the $i$-th coordinate of $x$ in the basis of eigenvectors $(v_1,\dots,v_d)$; in other words, $x=\sum^d_{i=1}\pi_i(x)v_i$.

Source: PÒLYA URNS AND OTHER REINFORCEMENT PROCESSES
Here the eigenvectors are of an irreducible matrix $R$, with associated eigenvalues $\lambda,\lambda_i$ for $i=2,\dots,d$, where $\lambda$ is the dominant eigenvalue, i.e. $\text{Re}(\lambda_i)<\lambda$.
What I don't understand is how could I interpret $\pi_i(x)$: from the description above it seems to me like it should be a scalar, and, to make sense in the formula above, since $x$ and the $v_i$ are vectors, the only other possibility is for it to be a matrix (I would discard this, just based on the description above).
The question arises when, further in tha paper, it is said

Notice that $e^{-sR}\pi_i(R_k)=e^{-s\lambda_i}\pi_i(R_k)$

Well, now clearly the exponential on the LHS is a matrix, while the one on the RHS is a scalar: the only possible conclusion is that $\pi_i(R_k)$ (here, $R_k$ denotes the $k$-th line of the matrix $R$) is a vector, which contradicts our previous suppositions.
What is happening here? Am I misinterpreting something?
In Summary : Are $\pi_i(x)$ & $\pi_i(R_k)$ scalars / vectors / matrices ?

I think there is a typo. It should have been :
$||e^{-sR}\pi_i(R_k)||_2^2=||e^{-s\lambda_i}\pi_i(R_k)||_2^2$
[[ Due to Eigenvector Property $Rv_i=\lambda_i v_i$ , we can change the Exponent ]]
It will then work out to :
$e^{-2s\lambda_i}||\pi_i(R_k)||_2^2$
DISCLAIMER :
I am not entirely convinced with the Definitions & Arguments given in the Paper.
[[ OP : Does this projection make sense ? My Opinion : No !! ]]
With intention to aid OP , I am merely suggesting what it could have / should have / must have been , without typos.
It is too long to put in Comment Box.

Thank you for your comment/answer! So, basically you assume that it should be a vector, right? Also, I don't know why should it work: that rule holds for eigenvectors $v_i$ associated to $\lambda_i$, if $v_i$ is an eigenvector, is $\pi_i(R_k)$ also an eigenvector?

Currently , I am more towards Scalar , though why writer uses $||\cdot||$ there is not clear !
